# Error: Failed to load plugin 'babel' declared in '.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-babel'

Tags: eslint, npm-start

Trying to run react app using `npm run react-start` but get this error while starting the development server.

[failed to load plugin 'babel' declared in '.eslintrc': cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-babel' require stack: - c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\config_*placeholder*_.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knvnc.png)

Here is my `.eslintrc` config file data:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "prettier"],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly",
        "window": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "babel",
        "jsx",
        "prettier"
      ],
```

I already installed `eslint-plugin-babel` using this command `npm add -D eslint-plugin-babel`.

version details :

```
npm -v : 6.14.8,
node -v: v14.15.0,
babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1"
```

Comment: Have you looked through your node_modules to see if it's there? If not, try `npm install`, otherwise, it might be the wrong version of eslint-plugin-babel for your version of eslint. If you share your versions, we can help more. Remember to get the versions from your package-lock.json, and not your package.json.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too today on my React App.. my solution:

1. run `npm install @babel/eslint-parser`
2. in `.eslintrc` file change `babel-eslint` to `@babel/eslint-parser`
3. create `.env` file and add `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true` to convert eslint errors to warnings
4. rerun the project

This solved my problem with these dependancies in `package.json`:

```
"react": "16.14.0"
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"eslint": "^8.36.0",
```